# stream.publish issue, share is not working

Tags: facebook, share

Two days ago I started to develop a new application, and I am just copied and pasted my other application, and then change it like how I want.

**The problem is that my old application worked perfectly with the share function, but the new one gives an error:

> An error occurred. Please try again later.

**I didn't forget to change APP_ID in FB.init.**

My share function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fb_share()
    {
        var publish = {
          method: 'stream.publish',
          message: 'Apie tai, kuo gyvena kauniečiai :)',
          attachment: {
            name: 'Kas vyksta Kaune tiesioginės transliacijos',
            caption: '',
            description: (
              'Kas vyksta Kaune vaizdas gyvai visiems kauniečiams!'
            ),
        media: [
              {
                type: 'image',
                href: 'http://www.facebook.com/Kaunas.gyvai?sk=app_292352984114290',
                src: 'http://misterp.lt/apps/share/Bambuser_app_icon.jpg'
              }
            ]
         ,href: 'http://www.facebook.com/Kaunas.gyvai?sk=app_292352984114290'
          },
          action_links: [
            { text: 'Tinklapis', href: 'http://www.facebook.com/Kaunas.gyvai?sk=app_292352984114290' }
          ],
          user_message_prompt: 'Kas vyksta Kaune tiesioginės transliacijos'
        };
         FB.ui(publish, function(response) { console.log(response); });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: By the way, share function works in chrome browser. On all others i get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. The problem was that I included the "Facebook live stream" plugin in my application and at the same time used fbAsyncInit to resize the iframe.

I just deleted `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=292352984114290&xfbml=1";` from the fb-live-stream plugin and the share function started to work.